# How can I center a element on the viewport width and height on mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there a way to center a element on the viewport of a mobile browser?

This means that when users pinch to zoom, they should still see the element ( let's say a div styled as a window ) on the center of their viewport.

Comment: What do you think should happen when the page has zoomed to the point where the element has overflowed the viewport?

Comment: have you tried position fixed? Because in my mind its simple, just offset the height of the browser with the height of the element. But when you zoom, the whole point is to zoom to a certain point, why would you want to keep an element in the middle?

Comment: @JamieHutber FYI `position: fixed` doesn't work on any iOS<6.

Comment: never had to test, so thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @JamieHutber this is a request from above. I didn't come up with this requirement. I personally believe we should disable zoom altogether and use css media queries to adapt content based on screen size. Since this might not be an option I was wondering if I was missing something by any chance.

Comment: I found a interesting solution. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that pinching to zoom triggers a window scroll event in ios browsers on my ipad mini, and on my android 4.something device.

```
$(window).on("resize scroll", function () {
    clearTimeout(pinchToZoomCheckTimer);
    pinchToZoomCheckTimer = setTimeout( function () {
        var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;

        dlgInner.width(width);
        dlgInner.height(height);
        dlgInner.css("top",window.pageYOffset+"px");
        dlgInner.css("left",window.pageXOffset+"px");
    }, 50);
});
```

This centers a div on the exact location used by the viewport. Since it is transparent, it "kinda" takes up the whole viewport. I've read that some browser report a few more pixels for the window.innerWidth, but I can live with a ~20px displacement.

http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/yFajk/show works while pinching to zoom, and scrolling after being zoomed in on my ipad mini and android nexus.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a straight way with HTML\CSS.

You can use JavaScript to detect page zooming and then calculate absolute sizes relative to original sizes and zoom factor.

Take a look at this:
[How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)
There is a very good and universal way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to position the div fixed, and centering it with a combination of margin and top / left:

```
.center {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:999;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#4679BD;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    left:50%;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HGtQA/

Comment: THe block will be misplaced after a zoom.

Comment: I am using a similar css centering method. It does not work with zoom.

Answer (score -2):

What do you mean by "they should still see the element" ? If a user zoom he will see only a part of an image. But if you want you can disable zoom with this meta :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Quite buggy on android 2.2

Comment: Flat out disabling zooming is kinda a dick move to people who genuinely want to zoom.

Comment: And yes for @Roko this sample code only works on iOS Safari. It was just a solution if he doesn't find a solution to his problem.

Comment: @Aliassse, thanks, I am using something similar to this, I am replacing the metatag when the popover shows up, basically disabling zoom. This works in my chrome browser on android 4.something as well.